# How to Change Monitor Resfresh Rate (Radeon Fury X) in Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: drivers, 15.10, radeon, amd-graphics, framerate

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 with GNOME shell (not 16.XX because Steam is having a hard time on that release right now) and I'm looking for a way to change my monitors refresh rates.

My GPU is an AMD Radeon R9 Fury X, and my monitors are the BenQ XL2730Z 144Hz, BenQ XL2420T, and Seiki SE42UMS.
All of my monitors are using Displayport1.2 (in the case of the Seiki SE42UMS, it's using an HDMI2.0->DP1.2 adapter.)

Any help would be appreciated and I'll try and port forth any more information that would be useful for helping resolve this issue I'm having.

Thanks.

Comment: Although your question is tagged 15.10, It is not specific to that version. But the above linked question should have answers. If that doesn't work edit your question how it fails. But if it turns to be specific to 15.10, your question might be closed. I suggest upgrading to 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I just want to apologize for wasting anyones time (my own included).

Here's what I did to change the refresh rates on all my monitors:

1. Open AMD Catalyst Control Center with superuser permissions `sudo amdcccle`
2. In Display Manager, go to the "Display Properties" tab and change your refresh rate there.